# How to use useState with arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, use-state

**The Problem**

I want to set categories, in a writing post page everything gets uploaded to the server except the category, I think its because its an Array

**Post Model `Post.js`**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        desc: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
        },
        categories:{
            type: Array,
        }

    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

**Creating Post in `Posts.js`**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

//CREATE POST
    router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
        const newPost = new Post(req.body);
        try {
            const savedPost = await newPost.save();
            res.status(200).json(savedPost);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
      });
```

**In Write Page I Used**

```
    export default function Write() {
    const [categories, setCats] = useState([]);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    const newPost = {
      username: user.username,
      title,
      desc,
      categories,
    };

if (file) {

      try {
        await axios.post("/upload", data);
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/posts", newPost);
      window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
    } catch (err) {}
};

return(
<form className="writeForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="" 
          className="writeInput writeCats" 
          onChange={(e) => setCats(e.target.value)}>
</input>
</form>
```

)

Now title, desc, username are stored in the server except categories, any one can help with how can I POST the categories to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [react-autcomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#checkboxes) to use multiple values, but in your case this is how to update the state:

```
const [categories, setCats] = useState([""]);

<input
  type="text"
  placeholder=""
  className="writeInput writeCats"
  value={categories[0]}
  onChange={(e) => setCats((state) => [e.target.value])}
/>;
```

Comment: thank you for referring to react-autocomplete, but the answer didn't work, it didn't save in the server